# Symfony2 checkbox choice field: disable one checkbox

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a task to make some of the checkboxes in a form choice field disabled, and some not. Is there an easy way to achieve that without rewriting choice field layouts?

Comment: Check my answer here, it's a quick and effective solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31535943/symfony-choice-type-with-disabled-options/34526846#34526846

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set on your choice field the disabled state :

```
$builder->add('myChoice', 'choice', array('attr'=>array('disabled'=>'disabled')));
```

Or you could use an EventSubscriber to listen on PostSetData event if you have some logic needed to set the disabled state.
Check [cookbook dynamic form generation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_generation.html) for implementation details.

Comment: Hi Flaveien, thanks for answer. I cant use first, simplest option because i have about 7 choice fields and 4 of them must have readonly state.
I think second suggestion can do the job. Can i calculate with EventSubscriber value from many fields? I think about making two subfields of type choice - one readonly and second without that flag and calculate value from them.

Comment: Yes you can do that. The event object will receive current form and data that you can access with `$event->getForm()` or `$event->getData()`. Then you will be able to perform any logic you need.

Comment: ok i tried that and works almost perfect. One think i cant understand its passing to my DataTransformer::reverseTransform names of my subfields instead of calculated value. Can you help me with that situation?

Comment: dont know how yet but it starts to work properly even without subscriber for binding data. Thank you very much for help :)

Answer (score 2):

I want to clarify something about the solution of Flavien, but I don't have sufficient reputation to comment under his post.

```
$builder->add('myChoice', 'choice', array('attr'=>array('disabled'=>'disabled')));
```

The use of 'disabled'=>'disabled' is wrong (because the right part is wrong). It works but disabled (left) accepts boolean and should receive true or false. In this case it really works because simply anything but 0 is true.

Why am I explaining this? Because maybe someone wants to use the same form in different places and just disable one input (in practice making it readonly). So he will feed a variable to the 'disabled' parameter and if that variable is not boolean it will always result in disabling the input.

tl;dr

```
 $builder->add('myChoice', 'choice', array('attr'=>array('disabled'=>true)));
```

or

```
$builder->add('myChoice', 'choice', array('attr'=>array('disabled'=>false)));
```