# How to set select option disabled in formtype disabled dynamically?

Tags: symfony

I have a form type in symfony2.5 that has choice type which has many options set dynamically as

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('service_id', 'choice', array(
        'label' => 'Service',
        'choices' => $this->getChoice()
    ));
    .......
    .......
}

protected function getChoice()
{
    $choices = array();

    $options = array(
        '1' => 'test1',
        .............
    );

    foreach($options as $key => $option)
    {
        if($key%2 == 0) {
            ....
        } else {
            ////disabled choice
        }
    }
}
```

How can i set this choices set disabled??

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using form event listeners and `finishView` method. Similar question has been answered before here - [How to disable specific item in form choice type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344639/how-to-disable-specific-item-in-form-choice-type)

Note that `PRE_BIND` event is deprecated. Use `PRE_SUBMIT` instead.

Quote:

> The events PRE_SUBMIT, SUBMIT and POST_SUBMIT were introduced in
>   Symfony 2.3. Before, they were named PRE_BIND, BIND and POST_BIND.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

Comment: When i use PRE_SET_DATA following error has occured.
A cycle was detected. Listeners to the PRE_SET_DATA event must not call setData()

Comment: I fixed my answer. It is actually `PRE_SUBMIT` event, that you need to use. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: still not working :(. Can you help me out adding disabled attribute to options in finishView??

Comment: as link provided by you $view->children['service_id']->children returns an empty array

Comment: Without seeing your code I can't really help you. Here is another way to solve it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299634

Comment: Please use something like PasteBin. Post your whole type class in readable format.

Comment: Try to output `get_class($view->children['service_id']);` in `finishView`. What do you get?

Comment: Symfony\Component\Form\FormView