# Symfony Choice type with disabled options

Tags: forms, symfony, custom-field-type

Is there any way with Symfony to render a `<select>` form type with disabled options, based on the truthyness of the given `choices` options ?

I saw [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344639/how-to-disable-specific-item-in-form-choice-type) (thanks to DonCallisto) about disabling choice expanded options ;
However I do not want to have an expanded choice.
I would like to keep a `select` element, with disabled `options`.

```
$builder->add('list', 'choice', array(
    'choices' => array(
        array(
            'value' => 1,
            'label' => '1',
            'disabled' => false
        ),
        array(
            'value' => 2,
            'label' => '2',
            'disabled' => false
        ),
        array(
            'value' => 3,
            'label' => '3',
            'disabled' => true
        )
    ),
    // Instead of
    // 'choices' => array(
    //     1 => 'Option 1',
    //     2 => 'Option 2',
    //     3 => 'Option 3'
    // )
);

# Which would render to the following element
<select [...]>
    <option value='1'>1</value>
    <option value='2'>2</value>
    <option value='3' disabled='disabled'>3</value>
</select>
```

I just can't find the way...
Is it necessary to build its own field type ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable specific item in form choice type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344639/how-to-disable-specific-item-in-form-choice-type)

Comment: Definitely missed this one, thanks ! I'll read it right know to see if it's the solution I'm looking for :)

Comment: Finally not a duplicate. the ````expanded```` option create a totally different behaviour between ````checkboxes```` and ````select```` elements.
But I'm afraid to understand that the Symfony core currently does not allow this kind of operations.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Since version 2.7, Symfony has introduced a way to set choice attributes using a callable, this is just what you need.

this code is taken from official Symfony [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-attr)

```
$builder->add('attending', ChoiceType::class, array(
    'choices' => array(
        'Yes' => true,
        'No' => false,
        'Maybe' => null,
    ),
    'choices_as_values' => true,
    'choice_attr' => function($val, $key, $index) {
        // adds a class like attending_yes, attending_no, etc
        return ['class' => 'attending_'.strtolower($key)];
    },
));
```

you can use the `'choice_attr'` and pass a function that will decide wether to add a  `disabled` attribute or not depending on the value, key or index of the choice.

```
...
    'choice_attr' => function($key, $val, $index) {
        $disabled = false;

        // set disabled to true based on the value, key or index of the choice...

        return $disabled ? ['disabled' => 'disabled'] : [];
    },
...
```

Comment: Great, I'll take a look, I'm currently testing SF3, I'll get back to this project :)

Answer (score 2):

According to the forms layout :

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig

and the choice_widget_collapsed and choice_widget_options,i don't think it's possible directly with the default Choice form of Symfony.

You can try :

- to build your own Choice form (by extending the existing one and adding parameters to option list, i think it's the best way)
- to use javascript/jquery to modify the options parameters at load time with the existing Symfony's Choice from

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot, apparently the ChoiceView do not seems to allow an option to be selected... https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/src/Symfony/Component/Form/ChoiceList/View/ChoiceView.php

However I would not even understand how to extend a choice type if all the core behing do not allow what I am trying to do :/ Any idea?

Comment: Extend it as a new form, allow new extra parameters to be held by your form, and create a new layout extending the existing form_div_layout to overwrite the "options" block. See official doc : [http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html) and [http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to load options from Entity.
You can create a new Entity `Attending` and use it with EntityType.

```
->add('attending', EntityType::class, [
'class' => Attending::class,
'choice_attr' => function($key, $val, $index) {
    if ($key->getId() == StaticVal) {
      return ['disabled' => 'disabled'];
    }
    return [];
}]
```

Here `StaticVal` can be any value that you want to disable it.
`$key` will give you an object value
`$val` will give you a value starting from 0 if you are using the placeholder option.